# How to compile Cassandra Thrift examples

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

I try to compile example code: http://pastebin.com/6aKzKxrg

javac -classpath cassandra-thrift-0.8.0.jar. CClient.java
or
javac CClient.java

Whatever what I do, I get errors like : http://pastebin.com/Xj4xP6Sj
I have got installed Cassandra in my system (Debian Squeeze)
Can anybody help for me? How to compile this example?
Thanks

Comment: You might also wish to consider using one of the existing high-level Cassandra clients - see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions

Comment: Yes, unless you are writing a new client (which I don't recommend unless you're extremely familiar with Cassandra), don't bother with raw Thrift.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a spurious "." at the end of your JAR file name which could be a reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including the other jars as well?

```
javac CClient.java -classpath /usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar
```